# Did O. Henry allude to Tom Sawyer in "The Gift of the Magi"?

Tags: allusions, mark-twain, o-henry

Sidney Porter (O. Henry) was a contemporary of Samuel Clemens (Mark Twain). They died the same year; Porter attended Clemens' funeral a few months before his own death.

Was Porter referring to Twain's character Tom Sawyer or to Twain himself in the passage bolded below (rectangled in [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0J5B.png))? Sawyer (and Clemens himself) had curly hair and both were also known for "skipping school."

> From "The Gift of the Magi" by O. Henry
>
> When Della reached home her intoxication gave way a little to prudence and reason. She got out her curling irons and lighted the gas and went to work repairing the ravages made by generosity added to love. Which is always a tremendous task, dear friends—a mammoth task.
>
> **Within forty minutes her head was covered with tiny, close-lying curls that made her look wonderfully like a truant schoolboy. She looked at her reflection...**

I assume also that the use of extravagant slang in O. Henry's *By Courier* (1906) was influenced by Twain's "Roughing It" (Buck Fanshaw / Scotty Briggs episode).

Comment: This quote is completely mangled. I don't know where you got it from, but it's not coherent English.

Comment: When Della reached home her intoxication gave way a little to prudence and reason . She got out her curling irons and lighted the gas and went to work repairing the ravages made by generosity added to love. Which is always a tremendous task, dear friends—a mammoth task. Within forty minutes her hair was covered with tiny close-lying curls that made her look wonderfully like a truant schoolboy. She looked at her reflection in the mirror ...

Comment: Who would have replaced *lying* (meaning *lying like a rug*) with *mendacity* (meaning *lying like a politician*). And there are other similar substitutions. Clearly, somebody changed it. trying to be funny,  Where did you find this quote? You have angered my curiosity (or do I mean pointed?).

Comment: It's from "O. Henry: 101 Stories" sample downloaded from amazon.

Comment: @PeterShor I did get a laugh from 'expensive buddies' for 'dear friends' though.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven I should ask for your money back on that.

Comment: @Spagirl: Free sample. I've been doing that lately-downloading all sorts of free samples of various authors.

Comment: Maybe somebody translated it into French, and then it was re-translated from French back into English.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven I don't know why anyone would do it, but I wonder if it's someone's weird idea of avoiding copyright, changing half the words for ones that a casual perusal of a thesaurus might suggest were equivalent.

Comment: @Spagirl: His works are in the public domain, as he died in 1910.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven Well I didn’t say it was a rationally founded attempt! ;) Do you have a link to the edition? I couldn’t find such a sample on Amazon UK.

Comment: @Spagirl: https://www.amazon.com/Henry-101-Stories-LOA-ebook/dp/B08MQ6Y39G/

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven: when I click on that link, the last story in the free sample is "Confessions of a Humorist", which is much earlier in the book than "The Gift of the Magi".

Comment: @PeterShor: It was meant to be a link to the book, not a particular location in the book. I believe "The Gift of the Magi" is the first story.